# Cannot enable Query Store on SQL Azure database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-query-store

One of our Azure SQL databases ran out of space recently which I believe resulted in Query Store switching over to "READ_ONLY".

I increased the size of the database however this has not resulted in the status changing even though running this query:

```
SELECT desired_state_desc, actual_state_desc, readonly_reason, current_storage_size_mb, max_storage_size_mb 
FROM sys.database_query_store_options
```

Suggests that there is enough space available:

```
desired_state_desc  actual_state_desc   readonly_reason current_storage_size_mb max_storage_size_mb
READ_WRITE          READ_ONLY           524288          522                     1024
```

I tried to alter the Query Store status to Read_Write by running this statement (as database server admin user):

```
ALTER DATABASE [QueryStoreDB]   
SET QUERY_STORE (OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE)
```

However, the statement failed with the following error:

```
User does not have permission to alter database 'QueryStoreDB', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.
```

Has anybody manged to switch SQL Azure Query Store to READ-WRITE so performance statistics start being collected again?

Comment: Please allow me to share this with Microsoft Engineers. Let me try to get some help.

Comment: That would be great Alberto, thanks. I was thinking of raising an Azure ticket but thought I would ask here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let’s try to clear the query store:

```
ALTER DATABASE [QueryStoreDB]   
SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR;  
GO
```

If that did not work, let’s run a consistency check.

```
ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseOne] SET QUERY_STORE = OFF;  
GO
sp_query_store_consistency_check
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseOne] SET QUERY_STORE = ON;  
GO
```

Try more options to troubleshoot this issue on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/best-practice-with-the-query-store) following article:

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. I ran the statements above, replacing [QueryStoreDB] and [DatabaseOne] with my database name. I then ran the statement to set operation mode to READ_WRITE and it worked as expected. Not sure if turning the query store on/off, running the consistency check or simply using the correct database name rather than [QueryStoreDB] fixed it??

Comment: I am glad to know it is now fixed. Thank you for letting me know. Enjoy SQL Azure!

Comment: Step 1 (SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR) and waited a minute then OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE was automatically set. Wasn't able to run step 2 due to permissions in Sql Azure.